# System.Web.Mvc.ModelState does not contain a definition for 'IsValid'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to move my login method from a controller action into a service class.  On compilation I'm being told that `System.Web.Mvc.ModelState does not contain a definition for 'IsValid'`  Am I missing a using statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ModelState` is both the name of a property on the Controller baseclass and the name of a class.

The code you moved was using the property, the error comes from trying to use the class instead.