# System.Web.MVC.ModelState does not have a definition for IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 application, I have a try-catch block in my `DeleteConfirmed` ActionResult that works well. So that I don't repeat code, I tried to place the indicated part of the following code block into a function outside the controller. I added the function to a custom`ErrorLog` class, but when I did, Intellisense indicated that "System.Web.MVC.ModelState does not have a definition for IsValid."

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537443/system-web-mvc-modelstate-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-isvalid) indicates that the error comes from trying to use the `ModelState` class instead of the property. However, that article did not indicate what should be done instead.

Below is the code I currently have followed by what I would like to do. My question is what I need to do differently so that I can save that `ErrorLog` entry to my database table?

**This is the code I have in my controller**

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    var _e = new ErrorLog().FillAndSend(e, "Delete", "ChildActionNames");

    // The following is identical each time I use this catch(Exception e) block

    UnitOfWorkErrorLog uw = new UnitOfWorkErrorLog();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        uw.ErrorLogRepository.Insert(_e);
        uw.Save();
        return View("ErrorManaged");
    }
}
```

**This is what I would like to do**:
*Catch block in controller*

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    var _e = new ErrorLog().FillAndSend(e, "Delete", "ChildActionNames");
    _e.SaveAlert(_e);  // pass ErrorLog instance to SaveAlert function
}
```

*Function now in `ErrorLog` class*

```
public void SaveAlert(ErrorLog _e)
{
    // this ErrorLog is already filled when called from controller
    UnitOfWorkErrorLog uw = new UnitOfWorkErrorLog();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        uw.ErrorLogRepository.Insert(_e);
        uw.Save();        
    }
}
```

Comment: ModelState is a property for the Controller class. You must pass It as parameter to the external class that will handle the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ModelState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx) is a property of the `Controller` base class which your controllers all inherit from. So you can use it in there but not outside of a controller. You can either pass the model state around as a parameter, or it makes more sense in this case to keep the logic in the controller:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
    _e.SaveAlert(_e);  // pass ErrorLog instance to SaveAlert function
```

As an additional point to note, it makes no sense to pass `_e` into the `SaveAlert` method. Instead you can reference it using `this` from inside the method.

Comment: This did the trick. I tested `_e.SaveAlert();` and in the model used `uw.ErrorLogRepository.Insert(this);`.  Seems to work.